# How do I make a random permutation with elements not assigned to themself

Tags: clojure

How do I write a function that takes a list of names and assigns each 
name another name which must not be the same.

This is how far I got:

```
(def people
    '("Peter" "Steve" "Mikel" "Andrea" "Hans" "Oliver" "Greg"))

(defn assign-people []
    (let [perm (map hash-map people  (shuffle people))]
        perm))
```

This functions yields for example:

```
({Peter Hans} {Steve Mikel} {Mikel Andrea} {Andrea Greg} {Hans Steve} {Oliver Oliver} {Greg Peter})
```

How do I prevent that a name is assigned to itself?

Edit: It should also be noted that no name is assigned twice or more times but only once

Comment: This is called a random derangement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be

```
(let [rand (shuffle people)
      second (rest (cycle rand))
      result (map vector rand second)]
    result)
```

What it does - is just generates a random sequence, then loops itself and shifts by 1. So for every list with length > 1 it guarantees element to not match.

The result is a list of vectors though, not sure if it's a problem for your task. If it is - you surely may change the result shape to anything you want.

Eg, to get a list of hash maps:

```
(let [rand (shuffle people)
      second (rest (cycle rand))
      result (map hash-map rand second)]
    result)
```

Comment: I would use `(rest (cycle rand))` instead of `(drop 1 (cycle rand))`, it is clearer and has better performance

Comment: I believe this would preclude cycles less than `n`, e.g. being paired with your partner for `n > 2`. That is, you can't get `({Hans Peter} {Peter Hans} ...)` here. This may or may not be desirable. Avoid binding to `second`, `rand` as these  are core functions. Not a problem here, just confusing.

Comment: @A.Webb that's a perfectly valid point I didn't think of actually. Even though the outcome is random, I agree it does not cover all the theoretically possible results (which in fact includes pairing a person to themselves). I think the "ideal" random solution would be to "loop until the result satisfies our requirements" which theoretically may take infinite amount of time.

Comment: You could avoid this problem with recursion with a function that avoids assigning a name to itself and has an accumulator that stores both the pairs built so far and the remaining names to be assigned. It would take me a bit of time to write so I can't do it now.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: it's not that easy. If you don't take account permutations and the current state - there is a chance you end up with the duplicate. EG: for an input set `1..3` you take 1 and pair it with random 2, then you take 2 and pair it with random 1, then you run the last iteration of recursion and it's 3-3, a duplicate. If you implement it - I'd like to see how you solve this dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

We can keep `shuffle`ing until we get an answer with no matches:

```
(defn derange [s]
  (loop []
    (let [cand (shuffle s)]
      (if (not-any? identity (map = cand s))
        cand
        (recur)))))

(derange people)
;["Hans" "Greg" "Andrea" "Peter" "Steve" "Mikel" "Oliver"] ; for example
```

---

This will not be satisfied with replacing a value with an equal one. If we want a random permutation, whether or not it changes every value, we can derange the indexes:

```
(defn derange [s]
  (let [v (vec s), nos (-> s count range vec)]
    (loop []
      (let [cand (shuffle nos)]
        (if (not-any? identity (map = cand nos))
          (map v cand)
          (recur))))))

(derange (repeat 5 \a))
;(\a \a \a \a \a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that n is the number of people, i.e.: `n = (count people)`:

```
(->> (cycle people) (partition 2) (take n))
```

If you need the pairs to be stored in hashmaps you can add `(map #(apply hash-map %))` after the take. If you need each time a random result you can shuffle the people first:

```
(->> (shuffle people) cycle (partition 2) (take n))
```

Comment: This method only happens to work because there are an odd number of people. When there are an even number you get half of the pairings required but repeated twice.